# Необработанное исключение типа "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" в mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, excel

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" в mscorlib.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800AC472

```
// вывод имени таблицы            
sheet.get_Range("A1:D2").MergeCells = true;
sheet.Range["A1"].Value = "Ведомость";
```

Выдает ошибку и не открывает документ Excel

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам необходимо добавить права Local Activation для asp_net аккаунта.

1. Открыть Component Services
2. Развернуть DCOM дерево
3. Найти Excel доккумент
4. Правый клик по элементу, выбрать свойства
5. Перейти на вкладку Security, выбрать Customize->Edit
6. Выбрать asp_net аккаунт и установить для него флаг Local Activation

В ссылке ниже приведен пример для решения проблем с документом Microsoft Word.
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?657928-failed-due-to-the-following-error-80070005-Access-is-denied.

Привожу скриншот примера из источника
[image: Скриншот из источника]

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Одной ссылки для ответа недостаточно.